# Looping through Dataset multiple times gives error

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

I have an OracleDataAdapter that fills my dataset, ds, with 1 row with 2 columns, a primary key and a number. I loop through it to display periodically in a loop box after a triggered event(right now a button press.

```
For Each DataRow As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        Try
            listB.Items.Add("ID: " & DataRow("racoreceivedid").ToString())
            listB.Items.Add("Phone: " & DataRow("phone").ToString())
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

But when I run through this snippet of code more than once I this error: ORA-06550
I originally got this error when trying to fill the dataset but had the wrong variable names in place. I'm not sure why I would get this error again if it runs once already.

Comment: bad naming there: `DataRow As DataRow`

Comment: What is the error message? Have you tried to debug the code?

Comment: The error message I get is from Oracle.
ORA-06550: Line1, Column 7:
PLS:00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "POLLSMS"
ORA-06550: Line1, Column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

It runs the first time fine but there after gives me that.